# How to get root path of a project resides in different system using java

Tags: java

I have a project called A in one system and project B in another system. Now I want root path of project B from project A. If I am writing

```
req.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/"), this is giving me project A root path.
```

Thanks in Adv.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if A is in one system and B is in another system, wouldn't A's root path have nothing to do with B's root path? So how would project A know or find where project B is?

Comment: I need to download a file from A, But the file is in different system where B project is running. But I am using same db for both project. So I guess if i can able to know root path of project B then i can access the file. Both system connected with LAN

Comment: So project B would have to somehow broadcast its root path to A, then A would have to SFTP (or a similar file transfer protocol) to B and `cd` to the path sent from B to download the file.

Comment: So for that I need web service call from A to B ?

Comment: I'm not too sure. But if your making a call to B from A, then you'll probably want B to respond with the root path to project B.

Comment: Call a webservice from A to B to get the file path, use this path with some FTP protocol to download the file.